# Updating the nested dictionary based on some condition

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following table

```
table = {}
table["A"] = {0: {"B":2, "C1":2},   1: {"C1":1}}
table["B"] = {0: {"C":1},           1: {"C2":1}}
table["C"] = {0: {"C1":1},          1: {"C2":1}}
```

and want to add the following values to the respective keys

```
c1 = {0:{"B":1}}    #This is for row "A"
c2 = {1:{"C":1}}    #This is for row "B"
c3 = {1:{"C2":1}}   #This is for row "C"
```

I want to insert the c1, c2, and c3 in the table such that for A, key will be checked against 0 or 1. If the key is present in the table, I need to go down to the values and check for the B inside the values of key 1. If B is present, i need to increment the value. Otherwise the {"B":1} will be added to  either 0 or 1 (based on the key)

I tried a number of techniques but always ended up with the error message or the corresponding values is not updated.

The resultant table should be

```
 table["A"] = {0: {"B":**3**, "C1":2},   1: {"C1":1}}
 table["B"] = {0: {"C":1},           1: {"C2":1}, **{"C":1}**}
 table["C"] = {0: {"C1":1},          1: {"C2":**2**}}
```

Updates: 
Although the solution provided by @RomanPerekhrest worked but when I tried to make these changes, i am getting the error message.

```
## to create the c1, c2, c3 etc from the list, I added this code. 
tr = ["A",0,"B",1,"C",1,"C2",1]
transition = {}
for i in range(1,len(tr)-2,2):
    transition[i] = {tr[i]:{tr[i+1]:1}}
## instead of the c1, c2 and c3 i want to use the transition
##c1 = {1:{"B":1}}
##c2 = {1:{"C":1}}
##c3 = {1:{"C2":1}}

##for k,d in zip(table.keys(), [c1,c2,c3]): this is working correctly. 

for k,d in zip(table.keys(), transition): ##the transition is generating error message for c_k,c_v in d.items():AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
     for c_k,c_v in d.items():
         if c_k in table[k]:
             for inner_k in c_v:
                 if table[k][c_k].get(inner_k):
                    table[k][c_k][inner_k] += c_v[inner_k]
                 else:
                     table[k][c_k][inner_k] = c_v[inner_k]
 print(table)
```

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen need your help

Comment: Is the level of nested dict constant? Or do you have more levels

Comment: @Bharath No the whole table and every thing inside the table is dynamic. Even the they c1,c2, and c3 are dynamic but I can manage that

Comment: @Abrar, what is the type of `transition` in your new code?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it is transition = {}. I updated in the question.

Comment: that new `transition` won't go as you think, define it as list `transition = []  for i in range(1,len(tr)-2,2):
    transition.append({tr[i]:{tr[i+1]:1}})`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thank you so much. That is exactly what I wanted but was missing the update method.

Comment: @Abrar, you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In straight-forward way:

```
table = {}
table["A"] = {0: {"B":2, "C1":2}, 1: {"C1":1}}
table["B"] = {0: {"C":1}, 1: {"C2":1}}
table["C"] = {0: {"C1":1}, 1: {"C2":1}}

c1 = {0:{"B":1}}
c2 = {1:{"C":1}}
c3 = {1:{"C2":1}}

for k,d in zip(table.keys(), [c1,c2,c3]):
    for c_k,c_v in d.items():
        if c_k in table[k]:
            for inner_k in c_v:
                if table[k][c_k].get(inner_k):
                    table[k][c_k][inner_k] += c_v[inner_k]
                else:
                    table[k][c_k][inner_k] = c_v[inner_k]

print(table)
```

The output:

```
{'A': {0: {'B': 3, 'C1': 2}, 1: {'C1': 1}}, 'B': {0: {'C': 1}, 1: {'C2': 1, 'C': 1}}, 'C': {0: {'C1': 1}, 1: {'C2': 2}}}
```

Comment: @RonamPerekhrestThank you so much the solution worked for me but I made some changes and now getting error message. I updated the post with the new changes. Can you have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from collections import Counter

table = {
         'A': {0: Counter(['B', 'C1'] * 2), 1: Counter(['C1'])},
         'B': {0: Counter(['C'      ]    ), 1: Counter(['C2'])},
         'C': {0: Counter(['C1'     ]    ), 1: Counter(['C2'])},
        }

modifications = {
                 'A': {0: Counter(['B' ])},
                 'B': {1: Counter(['C' ])},
                 'C': {1: Counter(['C2'])},
                }

for key_m, value_m in modifications.items():
    for key, value in table[key_m].items():
        value.update(value_m.get(key, []))

print(table)
```

Itsd using `collections.Counter` but they act as dicts for most of the parts except that their `collections.Counter.update()` method increases the value isntead of replacing it. If you want to convert a `collections.Counter` called `a` into a `dict` called `b` use `b = dict(a.items())`

Comment: Are you sure OP want this ?

Comment: @Adirio It will replace the existing values while I need to increment the values that already exist in the table. I will add it only, if they are not available in the table. 
thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Read it again and I'm not sure. Will give it a new shot.

Comment: @Abrar can you give this code a shot if it does what you wanted? `collections.Counter` are your friends for this kind of operations.